# How does gcc linker get the size of a function?

Tags: gcc, linker, symbols, elf

As a result of studying the ELF format, I can see that the object file has a symbol corresponding to each function, and the corresponding symbol table entry has a value of `st_size`, which means the size of the function.

The problem is that the executable file was successfully created even though I changed the `st_size` of the specific function in the object file and linked it. The following code is the test code I used.

```
// In main.c,

int main(void)
{
    myprintf("TEST");
}

// In log.c

#include <stdio.h>
void myprintf(const char *str)
{
    printf(str);
}
```

In the code above, I changed the `st_size` value of the `myprintf` function in the log.o file, and linked the log.o and main.o files. In the default, the `st_size` value was 0x13. I tested it by changing it to 0x00. I tested it by changing it to 0x40. But the `myprintf` function of the a.out result file is well up. How does the linker determine the size of each function?

Comment: On a side note, while I know your code is just an example, **please** don't pass a string variable as the first argument to `printf`.  If you just want to print a string by itself, use `puts` instead.  See [Format string attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Format_string_attack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly I'd like to begin with an old saying that it is more likely for humanity to find a theory of everything and unify quantum mechanics with general relativity rather than understand the optimizations and a decision tree of a linker.

back to our business, I've played with this on my machine and came to the conclusion that the only reasonable explanation for this, is that the linker doesn't truly need the size of a function in order to unify raw machine instruction from different compilation units into a single executable, and let's discuss why:

Let's say you have two compilation units, each containing three consecutive functions,
why would one need to know the size of each function? Isn't the fixed resolved virtual address granted to that function by that specific linker enough for relocation? and the true answer is - **it is sufficient to have nothing but the offset of a function within the object file to link different compilation units into one executables.**

However, with that being said, **some executable formats such as ELF** don't offer you an offset for a function machine code within a compilation unit, and you must calculate it yourself by indeed using the offset of that section within the ELF file and the size of each symbol entry within the section being pointed by the symbol table. which simply means, if you had **as I've said earlier, two compilation units with three functions each** after corrupting the size entry within the symbol table, as the linker would attempt resolving the compilation units into a single executable, it would simply corrupt it, and your executable would cause you segfaults quickly. I've attempted this at my home, and these are the results I've received:

when corrupting a symbol table's size entry of a compilation unit with **one function** nothing happens, as the entire text section's size (for this matter) is the exact same as that function's size, so the linker has no problem resolving it,
and when doing the same thing for compilation units with **three functions** it corrupts my executable, as the linker starts copying corrupted offsets of text from one compilation unit into the final executable.

Generally speaking, if you were to use an executable format which offers the linker an immediate offset of that function within the object file, without the need of calculation by size and section offset within the file, you'd probably end up with the same results even if you've had more than one function in a single compilation unit, **unless there is some sanity test done by the linker.** in my opinion the only reason a linker would need to use the size rather than the one I've just mentioned, is probably the need to clean out some section from redundant functions or variables not being referenced by anyone else (link time optimizations) and hence the need to recalculate relocation offsets for other referenced functions within that compilation unit, **or** to somehow recalculate relative jumps from within that same compilation unit.

hope this somehow answers your question, I'd be more than glad to help if you'd like a deeper demonstration of this